# Add a 2nd condition inside a WHERE clause?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I'm trying to add a second condition inside the WHERE in my foreach loop.

```
$customers = Customers::find()->where(['status' => 1])->orderBy('vip DESC, id ASC')->all();
```

Currently, I have it filtering where status=1 but I need to also add where 'rank' does not equal the text "Can".

The reason I need StackOverflow is that I've tried to find the answer on the web but I have a text comparison and a new query method I haven't used before so I can't research well.

How do I add the additional condition in the WHERE clause "AND 'rank' != 'Can'?

If I had to guess at it, I'd write it like this (which likely wrong)

```
 $customers = Customers::find()->where(['status' => 1])
    ->andwhere (['rank' !=> 'Can'])
    ->orderBy('vip DESC, id ASC')->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the amazing [ActiveQuery documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#andWhere()-detail), you have to use `andWhere()` method:

```
$customers = Customers::find()->where(['status' => 1])
   ->andwhere (['not', ['rank' => 'Can']])
   ->orderBy('vip DESC, id ASC')->all();
```

OR:

```
->andwhere (['<>', 'rank', 'Can'])
```

Please remember, that `PHP` **don't have** `!=>` comparision operator!

Answer (score 0):

In Yii i think you need change andwhere to andWhere.
or try this

```
$customers = Customers::find()->where("status = 1 and rank!='Can'"])->orderBy('vip DESC, id ASC')->all();
```